# less calls nano instead of vi

Tags: command-line, vim, less

In the default configuration of Ubuntu 18 LTS server, pressing the V key in `less` calls the `nano` editor instead of `vi` while none of the environment variables `$LESSEDIT`, `$VISUAL` or `$EDITOR` are set.

I was able to restore the correct behavior as documented in `man less` with `update-alternatives --set editor /usr/bin/vim.basic` but this proves `less` executes `editor` instead of `vi`.

Is this a documentation bug (Ubuntu behavior intentionally differing from default upstream `less` behavior) or a bug in less or is it my fault (did I miss something) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a documentation bug in the man page, the behavior is documented in `/usr/share/doc/less/README.Debian`).

In Debian and its derivatives (like Ubuntu) programs must use `editor` as standard editor if neither `$VISUIAL` nor `$EDITOR` is set, see [the Debian policy manual](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-customized-programs.html#editors-and-pagers).

Comment: Do you think I should create a Debian documentation bug for this or will that be ignored anyway in favor of more important bugs ?

Comment: The `less` package already contains a patch for the manpage so the maintainer seems to care about this kind of things.